# “Track the next one” doesn’t update/refresh the profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, badges, badge-progress

After earning a new badge you have two options in the your profile page:

1. Track the new one
2. Let us pick

> [image: next badge]

If you select “let us pick” the page will refresh and all looks fine, you will see the next recommended badge in this section. But if you tap on the “track the new one” and select the next badge - nothing will happen until you do manually refresh the page.

As far as I remember selecting the next badge manually in this case should refresh the page (at least badge block of the profile page) automatically.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug. Tested it aswell, same outcome.

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSO: [UI doesn't update when you pick a new badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387320/1478931)