# How is the recommended next badge determined exactly?

Tags: support, profile-page, badge-progress

According to [Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/295232), the

> "Progress to next badge" bar automatically selects the badge you're closest to earning (or that's most logical to go for next)

While "the badge you're closest to earning" is pretty easy to determine: it's the bar with the most progress, I'm wondering what "most logical to go for next" means. Because right now on Meta Stack Exchange, I can track two badges: Illuminator and Legendary. My progress for Illuminator is 66.40% and for Legendary it's 66.67%, yet *Illuminator* is shown as the recommended next badge:

[image: Select your next badge]

On some child metas where I barely have any activity, Student is shown as recommended next badge with a progress of 0/1, but I do have cast some votes so I have a small progress towards e.g. Civic Duty. So obviously there is some other logic at work, but what?

Comment: I was *trying* to test this out by keeping my progress toward Illuminator at 60/500 and that toward Epic at 6/50, and then earning the Socratic badge (the last one remaining), but unfortunately my Illuminator progress turned to 61 recently, so...

Comment: Related info: ["Let us pick" = "Recommend"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304836/282094).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "most logical" mean about the next badge on the profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259390/what-does-most-logical-mean-about-the-next-badge-on-the-profile), but the answer with 4 upvotes disagrees with [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330614/282094) which I believe is much more likely to be correct. The other questions was asked long before this one, thus a dupe; even if the correct answer is here.

Comment: You've giving enough reasons to close it the other way around, which I just did (I forgot about my dupehammer, sorry about that). See [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/295232)

Comment: Glorfindel, that's OK. It's correct and important that they are linked one way or the other due to [this old *duplicate*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298953/3648282) on Stack Overflow which has a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298953/how-is-a-badge-recommended#comment218880_298953) (as an answer) which links to the other (older) question. [exhales]

Comment: @Rob true, thank you for finding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the next badge generate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258889/how-does-the-next-badge-generate)

Comment: Again, I think the canonical answer to that question is now here, so I've closed the other way around.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It runs through the following logic tree, stopping at the first recommendation that matches:

- Recommend Excavator if Excavator is enabled, user doesn't have Excavator, and user has edit questions and answers privilege.
- Recommend Custodian if the current site is not a child meta, user doesn't have Custodian, and user has access review queues privilege.
- Recommend Supporter if user doesn't have Supporter and user has vote up privilege.
- Recommend Critic if user doesn't have Critic and user has vote down privilege.
- Recommend most progressed badge that user doesn't currently have and has at least 50% progress already.
- Recommend Informed if the current site is not a child meta and user doesn't have Informed.
- Recommend Autobiographer if user doesn't have Autobiographer.
- Recommend Student if user doesn't have Student.
- Recommend Teacher if user doesn't have Teacher.
- Recommend Editor if user doesn't have Editor.
- Recommend most progressed badge that user doesn't currently have, no progress minimum.

Note that for the two points above that check for the "most progressed badge", the progress is stored as an integer percentage with the decimal portion truncated. So in your example where Illuminator is 66.4% and Legendary is 66.6%, they're both truncated to 66%. In case of ties, the first one alphabetically is recommended.

Comment: "Excavator is enabled" - does that mean the site is at least 6 months old?

Comment: There's a site setting to turn the "ancient" badges on/off though I don't believe they're actually disabled anywhere.