# Could we get a clearer badge progress tracker for the Curious/Inquisitive/Socratic badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges, asking-days-badges

So I've asked 5 questions each with a positive score (and well-received, I guess) on 5 separate days. **The badge indicator says that the task is complete (5/5)**, but I haven't been awarded that badge.

Here's my profile: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/356843/justin?tab=questions

[image]

After clicking on the badge, it says that I still need a "positive question record". I don't have any recently deleted or closed questions and I can't seem to remember any questions that have been closed or deleted in the past year.

[image]

It turns out [I still have some work to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361614/why-wasnt-my-curious-badge-awarded-even-after-it-indicated-ive-met-the-requi#comment1206482_361614), but there's no way for me to see it directly in the badge progress tracker, which is filled up entirely, giving the impression that the task is complete. You can only find out now that the task isn't complete by clicking on the badge progress tracker.

I'm aware of [this request to make the positive record score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234963/369802) visible, but **can we also have a better indication in the progress tracker that the task hasn't been completed yet?**

Comment: Either way, this looks like a bug. Either the badge has not been awarded because the OP doesn't have a positive record, in which case the badge indicator should not be saying the task is complete, or the OP does indeed meet all criteria and yet has received no badge. So any way you look at it, there's a bug.

Comment: @terdon, your modification / interpretation would make this a duplicate of that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234956/282094 - it's a "you gotta click it" badge, details in the fine print™.

Comment: @terdon The dialog does clearly state OP [still needs a positive record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75cTD.png), so it doesn't seem like a 'badge not awarded' case to me. I agree the indicator is confusing: It seems to be tracking only the 5/5 well-received questions needed. [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234963/369802) a feature request, requesting that the track record be made more visible too.

Comment: Justin, the English.SE mod has just confirmed there are 13 old deleted questions on your account. None were scored negative, but 1 was closed. So that makes your question record score for now (20-1-13)/20 = 0.3. You're going to need at least 8 more positive questions before you get your badge...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - Ah, that clarifies a lot.. Guess I have a long way to go.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - Can the mods close this question, or should I just delete it?

Comment: Sure, no worries. I've edited the previous calculation a little as it turned out there was also 1 closed question. I can close/delete it, but it *may* be better for future curious badges on this site to actually try and make it... a feature request to improve the badge tracker for this badge? I'm willing to give it an edit for you, if you'd like :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - Sure, go ahead :)

Comment: Related: [Don't recommend the asking days badge series in the user profile if user doesn't have a positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357447)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell it does indeed. It is the counter (5/5) that is confusing since that suggests the criteria have been met when they actually haven't. Now that I realize that is only counting the questions and not the ratio, it makes more sense. And now that I see that clicking on it _does_ explain in more detail it makes even more sense.

Comment: Note that there is **no single, simple scalar metric** to track here. You either have a positive question asking record or you don't, and the only way to flip that metric, is to continue posting questions that are positively received. There is no fixed number of questions that'll get you there, because your total record of questions can be voted on, closed or reopened, deleted or un-deleted.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: now that this post has been turned into a feature-request, do you think this could be a duplicate of [Give users a way to see their "Positive Question Record" score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234963)? I can't vote on this post any more, as I already voted on the previous revision (also a dupe).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried to avoid making this another duplicate of that, by not asking for seeing the score but just for a clearer progress indicator on the badge. Especially since the score doesn't say so much if you don't know it's supposed to be 0.5 or higher. So I'm probably not the right person to ask (little biased with my own work here :P ).