# View question record

Tags: feature-request, asking-days-badges

If a question record is needed for some badges, why can't I see what it is?

Since it’s only some calculation, which is already being made, it seems rather simple to display it on the user's profile page. It should display what affected the record, so we can know how to improve it.

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. Isn't [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) enough? Combined with the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)? Why do we need to cramp all info into the user profile page and/or badge selector dialog?

Comment: @rene Because it's [confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357447/dont-recommend-the-asking-days-badge-series-in-the-user-profile-if-user-doesnt) for the tracker to show a higher than 100% progress for a badge but not have that badge be awarded.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog the confusion is part of the game ...

Comment: @rene no, its not enough. We can get to 100% progress like Sonic said and have no idea why we won't get the badge and what we need to fix in order to receive it

Comment: [*we have no idea idea why we won't get the badge*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-days-badges) ... we don't have to spoon feed users ...

Comment: @rene I have no idea what you linked to.. And what does "spoon feed" have anything to do with this feature request? Maybe lets not display any questions on the site because it spoon feeding instead of letting people open hard cover books?