# Why don't I have the Curious badge?

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress, asking-days-badges

On Stack Overflow, I am tracking the Curious badge:

[image: image of the Curious badge, with 7/5 questions asked and the progression bar full]

As you see, it states that I made 7 good questions out of the target which is 5 and it still shows me that I didn't get the badge.

It doesn't show up in my list of all badges either.

Why don't I have it yet?

Comment: You don't have a positive question record according to the tooltip for it on your profile.

Comment: As the duplicate says, while you've met the asking days criterion, you haven't met the requirement for a positive question record. The "progress" in your user profile only accounts for the former, not the latter.

Comment: If the system automatically recommended you that badge as your next one and you didn't select it manually, please consider supporting [my feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357447/dont-automatically-recommend-an-asking-days-badge-in-the-user-profile-if-user-d) asking that it not be automatically recommended if you aren't eligible to earn the badge on the basis of having too low of a record score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your profile, clicking on the badge displays the message 'need positive question record' with an 'x' mark next to it, meaning that your question record has too many downvoted, closed, or deleted questions.
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The exact formula used to calculate the positive question record can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/1278220).