# Possible bug about socratic badge not being awarded

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

On *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*, I came across a user with 411 questions, but [no Socratic badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/460999/john-zimmerman?tab=badges&sort=class) even though [245 questions had positive votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/460999/john-zimmerman?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=9) (I didn't check whether all of them are on separate days).  Shouldn't he have received two gold Socratic badges by now?

I found a similar instance on *[Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour)* where the user had 423 questions (out of which [303 have positive score](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/21496/kadalikatt-joseph-sibichan?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=11)), but [no Socratic badge](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/21496/kadalikatt-joseph-sibichan?tab=badges).  If all 303 questions were on separate days, shouldn't he have received three gold Socratic badges by now?

Comment: Probably those users have many deleted questions with negative score. When the overall negative, closed, and deleted questions is over half the total, Socratic badge won't be awarded at all.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard I see.  Is that by design, or an oversight?  Surely for these 2 example users, their persistent posting of subsequently positively voted questions have redeemed them from "the penalty" of closed/deleted questions?  In other words, why wouldn't the system help them overcome their past "misdeeds" ?

Comment: That is the design, you can see the formula and explanation in the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated).

Comment: TL;DR: a question being downvoted, closed, and/or deleted has each of those count against the user's record score multiple times, not just once. It can take singificantly more well-received questions to make up for just a few questions with multiple negative marks. For an example, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357447/dont-automatically-recommend-an-asking-days-badge-in-the-user-profile-if-user-d), the paragraph beginning with *This situation is more common*.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks, that post explains a lot.  I have a feeling my findings must have been addressed before.  And you can add this question to the sentence ".... again and again and again and again ..." :-)

Comment: That explains the question record requirement. With regards to the number of days requirement, it's also worth noting that a single question getting a negative mark will make that day not count, even if the user posted one or more positively-received questions on the same day.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple That question has specifically to do with the badge *tracker* in user profiles not considering the question record score and showing 100% completion without a badge award, because the user earned the required qualifying days but doesn't have the required record score.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Understood.  Thanks for taking the time to explain the system to me.  As a software developer myself, I love it how Meta.SE becomes a "self-documenting" system (albeit with human help).  Good job, guys !